# ipywidget for jupyterlab error with left and top panel

Tags: jupyter-lab

after install ipywidgets

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

then install jupyterlab manager

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

my jupyterlab has problem to show the left and top panel. even after I run the clean code, the issue still exist

```
jupyter lab clean
```

I checked my version

```
jupyter --version
```

It shows

[image]

I have tried reinstall many times it still does not work
has anyone meet this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this problem when I use jupyterlab 1.1.1 and I installed jupyter labextension. I solved by downgrade jupyterlab to 1.1.0 and it's work. I think newest version of jupyter lab is not stable.
`pip install -U jupyterlab==1.1.0`

Comment: but I am using 1.0.2 version